Pyinstaller in virtual environment still yields very large EXE file
I have a Python code of 78 lines using the following packages:
import pandas as pd
import base64
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import os
import win32com.client as win32
import pathlib

I ran the following commands:
venv\Scripts\activate
python -m pip install pandas
python -m pip install pybase64
python -m pip install bs4
python -m pip install pywin32
python -m pip install pyinstaller
pyinstaller --onefile to_HTML.py

I have created a virtual environment in which I installed only the above packages.
Yet the EXE file created is 740Mb!!
What am I doing wrong? How can I reduce it?

Did you check how large the folder is that contains your virtual environment? The point of PyInstaller is that it wraps all of your code's dependencies into the exe file. Even if you only installed 4 dependencies in your virtual environment, this doesn't mean that only those 4 dependencies will get wrapped – because their dependencies need to get wrapped, as well. And at least from pandas I know that it has quite a few of them. So all I want to say is: maybe the resulting file size is not that unexpected?

The venv folder size is 180 Mb.

As mentioned here, pandas tends to produce huge exe files. If needed, you can use the --onedir option instead of the --onefile option.

It doesn't look like you've installed pyinstaller within your virtual environment. I suspect it's attempting to use your global pyinstaller, which may be attempting to wrap any other packages you've installed globally.
Try this:
venv\Scripts\activate
python -m pip install pyinstaller
# install other dependencies as needed
venv\Scripts\pyinstaller.exe --onefile to_HTML.py

Based on my quick test case, I get a very different file size when running with the virtual environment pyinstaller vs. the global one.

No. This is not the case. I did install pyinstaller otherwise it could not have used a package outside the virtual environment. I will add the install command for clarity above

@gtomer Did you try explicitly invoking the pyinstaller.exe in the venv folder? Otherwise it might be finding the one wherever else in your path it’s located.

You could try where pyinstaller to double check where your shell's grabbing the command from.

if where doesn't output anything, try explicitly with where.exe pyinstaller

I tried to reproduce your problem and failed. So, rather than an actual answer, the following is advice for figuring out the problem yourself.¹
First, here is what I did:

Installed Python 3.11 on Windows 11.
Created an environment with exactly the packages that you described.
Created a Python script to_html.py with exactly the imports that you described, but no additional code other than print("Done") after the imports.
Created an executable from to_html.py with PyInstaller, just as you described.

I ended up with an executable of roughly 38MB, which is consistent with the findings from the question that is referenced in @AmericanJael's comment.²
Here is what I suggest:

Install a tool that helps you extract your executable – because after all, a PyInstaller executable is nothing but a fancy self-extracting archive. You can use, for example, pyinstxtractor-ng for this purpose.
Extract your executable. You should end up with a directory that contains the contents.
Analyze the sizes of the subfolders from the extraction result. If you want to use a graphical tool, you might want to have a look at something like WinDirStat or a more modern-looking alternative. If you want to use your terminal, see, for example, here. I would assume,

either some subfolder, corresponding to a specific library, should be unexpectedly large,
or there are some unexpected subfolders, corresponding to libraries or other content that should not be there (or both).


Depending on the result, continue your hunt for a solution from there.

Good luck!
¹) I chose to write an answer rather than a comment for the better formatting options and unrestricted length. No need to vote and/or accept.
²) By the way, the answers to this question might give you more ideas towards your solution.

It's possible that you are using your global venv to install these packages, and for some reason or another your 'activate' call isn't working. I've noticed this happen on my windows computers sometimes - I'll run venv/Scripts/activate but for some reason the terminal doesn't recognize that it worked. It might be a bug or just my own user error but it happens to me all the time.
Try these commands to force it to use the venv pip.exe:
venv\Scripts\pip.exe install pandas
venv\Scripts\pip.exe install pybase64
venv\Scripts\pip.exe install bs4
venv\Scripts\pip.exe install pywin32
venv\Scripts\pip.exe install pyinstaller
venv\Scripts\pyinstaller --onefile to_HTML.py

You may need to check exactly what the pyinstaller command would be as I can't verify that that's true right now. Look in venv/Scripts to see if it's pyinstaller or pyinstaller.exe ect.
I know you said you verified that you weren't using the global pip to install this, but I do think this is well worth a try.
